# Backbone views events firing repeatedly in routes

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I have a [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org) application that contains a router file and some views , and also i'm using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org) to add views to routes and add templates to views. here is my codes :

**routes.js**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": "getLogin",
    "login": "getLogin",
    "register": "getRegister",
    "forget-password": "getForgetPassword"
},
getLogin: function() {
    require(['views/auth/loginView'], function(view) {
        view = new this.LoginView();
    });
},
getRegister: function() {
    require(['views/auth/registerView'], function() {
        view = new this.RegisterView();
    });
},
getForgetPassword: function() {
    require(['views/auth/forgetPasswordView'], function() {
        view = new this.ForgetPasswordView();
    });
},
});

var route = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**loginView.js**

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#wrapper',
initialize: function() {
    NProgress.start();
    this.render();
},
render: function() {
    require(['text!partials/auth/login.html'], function(t) {
        var json = { title: 'title', formName: 'frmLogin' };
        var template = _.template(t);
        $('#wrapper').html(template(json));
    });
    NProgress.done();
},
events: {
    "click #btnLogin": "login"
},
login: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('some message');
}
});
```

also `registerView.js` and `forgetPasswordView.js` are similar to `loginView.js`.

**now!** when i change routes multiple times and hit `#btnLogn` it fires `alert('some message');` function multiple times...!

Comment: You have accidental global `view`s in two of your router methods. You're creating views that are bound to `#wrapper` (a bad idea IMO) rather than letting the views create and own their own `el`s. I see no `view.remove()` calls so you never bother to destroy your views and so you have memory leaks and zombie views. Fix all that and try again.

Comment: @muistooshort i think you are right...! let me try it.

Comment: @muistooshort what is your advice? can you help me?

Comment: @543310 You should keep a reference to created views. And make your to remove the existing one before creating another one...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [un-delegating](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) the events in the view, on route change?

You could override the `route` method ([annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-189)) in your `AppRouter` and run it before each route is rendered.

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
    view.undelegateEvents();
    return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Note: Just an idea, not tested with your code